# Quickest way to calculate the average growth rate across columns of a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given an array such as:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]])
```

What's the quickest way to calculate the growth rates of each row so that my results would be `0.52083333333333326`, and `0.13640873015873009` respectively.

I tried using:

```
>>> np.nanmean(np.rate(1,0,-a[:-1],a[1:]), axis=0)
array([ 5.        ,  2.5       ,  1.66666667,  1.25      ,  1.        ])
```

but of course it doesn't yield the right result and I don't know how to get the axis right for the `numpy.rate` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
In [262]: a = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]]).astype(float)
In [263]: np.nanmean((a[:, 1:]/a[:, :-1]), axis=1) - 1
Out[263]: array([ 0.52083333,  0.13640873])
```

Answer (score 3):

To take your approach using `numpy.rate`, you need to index into your `a` array properly (consider all rows separately) and use `axis=1`:

```
In [6]: np.nanmean(np.rate(1,0,-a[:,:-1],a[:,1:]), axis=1)
Out[6]: array([ 0.52083333,  0.13640873])
```